# React navigation modals on react native web - Prevent url path update

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I have a react native app that we are implementing the react native web version using: [React native web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/), the app uses the latests react native navigation library.

So far, mostly everything is working except for modals, the problem that i have is that when i open a modal, the URL path on web updates (I.E: from `/signup` if i open a modal it switch to `/legalAgreementModal?QUERY_PARAMS....`), so if i refresh the page the modal works but i can't close the modal anymore. I thought about adding a conditional on the modal to goBack if there is anything to go back to, but the problem is that i have too many modals that can go back to different screens so it will be a huge change if i have to add that logic to every modal.

My question is, is there a way to avoid modals to update my path? So if user refresh they lost the modal but they are on the original screen? Perhaps another workaround that you guys may know could help also!.

Thanks!

I tried adding a conditional on modal close action, adding empty string as the modal path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are struggling with this as well. We wish there was a way to have screens that - when navigated to - do not change the path in the URL and otherwise do not get their state from the path. Then when the user refreshes, they are shown the screen behind the modal with the modal closed.